# Proof for halting problem is recursively enumerable

Tags: computability, formal-languages, decidability

So, I know the proof for Halting Problem is **not recursive** using diagonalization. We prove it using proof by contradiction. First we assume HP is recursive which implies there is a Total Turing Machine. And prove it is not possible by contradiction.

But the proof just says Halting Problem is **not recursive**. It **doesn't** say Halting Problem is **recursive enumerable**.

So how to prove Halting Problem is **recursive enumerable**

Comment: You can run the programs and note every program that halts. Every halting program will eventually be noted.

Comment: @Peter So we know that some programs will halt, does that prove its recursive enumerablity?

Comment: You have to show that there is an algorithm that, given the code for some program, outputs YES if the program halts, but is not required to do anything if it doesn't. The desired algorithm is the one Peter described: just run the program given in input. If it halts, you will see it, and you can output YES, otherwise you never halt (which is fine).

Comment: @Manlio With the same logic won't **diagonal language** ({ x | Mx halts on input x }) be recursive enumerbale? But for a fact I know that it is not recursive enumerable

Comment: Did you mean "Mx does not halt on input x"? The set you described is $\emptyset'$ (the Turing jump of the empty set). According to the textbook you are reading, the halting problem may be defined as $\emptyset'$ or something like $\{ \langle x,y \rangle : \varphi_x(y)$ halts $\}$. For most purposes it doesn't really matter, the two sets are $1$-equivalent, in particular they are both r.e..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A recursively enumerable language is a formal language for which there exists a Turing machine (or other computable function) that will halt and accept when presented with any string in the language as input but may either halt and reject or loop forever when presented with a **string not in the language**.

The key words in the above definition is "string not in the language ", so now if one has a computable function to accept all the valid strings , which in the context of the question would be all computable functions, then the HP is recursively enumerable.

One such algorithm is already mentioned in the comments by Peter under the question...
Which is to run every possible program, and register all the halting ones.

It guarantees to find 'all' the computable functions eventually, and rejecting or looping 'only' on non-computable functions.

AND with the above logic the recursive enumerability of the **diagonal language** can't be inferred. Since any computable function deciding the valid strings will enter a infinite loop at $ x=D $  i.e. the diagonal language's own number, since any computable function must accept the symbol at $ x=D $, cuz its a valid string in the diagonal language , to make it recursively enumerable, but no such function exists ,therefore the diagonal language is not recursively enumerable.

Comment: You wrote `Since any computable function deciding the valid strings will enter a infinite loop at x=D`. But, as per the definition of **diagonal language** ({ x | Mx **halts** on input x } every valid string will halt right? Based on this we have a turing machine which accepts all valid strings. Hence it should be **recursively enumerable** right?

Comment: I didn't completely read the definition u gave, usually the defacto definition given to the term - " diagonal language " contains a negation.. refer this site - http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~aho/cs3261/Lectures/L15-Diagonalization_Language.html#:~:text=The%20Diagonalization%20Language%20Ld,enumeration%20of%20all%20Turing%20machines.

Comment: Although going by your definition the Turing machine deciding that language halts on a given string iff the Turing machine corresponding to the number halted on it, so it's nothing but a weaker version of HP, and ofcourse it must be recursively enumerable, I think you got confused regarding the definition of the diagonal language

Comment: Ah yes, got it. Thanks.

Comment: @Mike welcome..  hey mike if your problem is solved can you accept the answer as valid , it helps others to know it's a valid answer

Comment: I am new this site. I should just press the tick mark on the left side of answer right?

Comment: hey bro, just a casual question came to my mind... were you also studying godel's incompleteness theorem while you asked this question ? was going through my previous answers.... so just casually asking......

Comment: I as studying it now. But not while asking this question.

Comment: Ok... for some reason i thought you were studying it that time.....  anyways.... goodluck.....

Comment: Thanks. Good luck to you too.